# How to restrict a user from selecting more than 10 items from a CheckBox ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I've searched all over and cant find a solution that works for my situation. I currently have a custom checkbox adapter extending from ArrayAdapter that holds 'Food' objects ('Food' contains 2 attributes 1. Boolean:Selected and 2. String:Name). When the listView loads I have 10 items that are selected by default. I need to allow a user to unselect/select options but limit them to only 10 choices.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CheckBoxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Food> foodList;

    int counter = 0;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtView;
        CheckBox chkBox;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.food_text);
            chkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.food_box);
        }
    }

    public CheckBoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Food> food) {
        super(context, 0, food);
        this.context = context;
        foodList = food;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Food food = getItem(position);

        View row = convertView;

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_category_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);

            //Not sure if we need to use this - for now i think its useless...
            viewHolder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    //foodList.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                    if(isChecked){
                        counter++;
                    }
                    else if(isChecked){
                        counter--;
                    }
                    if(counter > 10){
                        foodList.get(getPosition).setSelected(!buttonView.isChecked());
                        counter--;
                    }

                }
            });
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

        }

        viewHolder.chkBox.setTag(position); // This line is important.
        viewHolder.txtView.setText(foodList.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.chkBox.setChecked(foodList.get(position).isSelected());

        return row;

    }

}
```

Comment: Just manage count of the selected number and disable the check possibillity if count is 10

Comment: I am having issues when i scroll down and reveal more checkbox's.. I am pretty sure its from Holder recycling each item. Not sure how to fix it though.. @yshahak

Comment: Create one list. Add item id into list when checked. Check for list size every time onClick of checkbox.

Comment: without some code it will be hard to help

Comment: @yshahak Edited and updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like that:

```
viewHolder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int getPosition = (int) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
            //foodList.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
            if (isChecked) {
                counter++;
            } else {
                counter--;
            }
            if (counter > 10) {
                buttonView.setChecked(false); // no need to do counter-- because the listener will trigger again
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hmm, close... but the default choices dont work. The checkbox's are empty and it wont allow me to select a single box.

Comment: Sorry, jest start with counter = 0 as you did in first place

Comment: Thank you that issue got fixed. Now, I cant select any checkbox's, even if i unselect a few...Hmmm.

Comment: Just needed to decrement counter in if(counter>10).Thank you for your help man, appreciate the effort!

Comment: I noticed the comment you left under the if statement, why is not only working with counter there? Checking the logs, it seems the counter goes up to 20 when the layout is loaded and after decrements it goes down to 10 so thats why i was not able to select any after that..

Comment: How it go up to 20? you told that the initalize number of your array is 10.

Comment: Not exactly, I have default list stored in an ArrayList, so when the the activity runs it populates the checkbox's based on the default list, which happens to be 10 items.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use `setOnCheckedChangeListener`. getView call every time on scroll and checkbox is being set every time so listener called.

I recommended you to use `setOnClickListener` for cehckbox and maintain checkbox in that way.

```
    viewHolder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
            //foodList.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.

         if(viewHolder.chkBox.isChecked()){
             viewHolder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
             counter--;
         }
         else{
             if(counter < 10){{
             viewHolder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
             counter++;
             }
         }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Having an issue with ViewHolder.. "Variable viewHolder is being accessed from inner class, needs to be declared final"

Comment: I tried implementing this. The 10 defaults are checked but now I cant select or unselect any checkboxes.

Comment: That didn't seem to resolve the issue. Same problem :/

Comment: Well its the same issue, the 10 are selected and I cant select or unselect any of them.